# Nightwatch.js select first element in select

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I know I can select a value with

```
selector: 'select[id="country"] option[value="2"]'
```

but I got different enviroments with multiple vars. How can I select the first value in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of how to select the first value in a dropdown, use the chrome dev tools inspector and from that copy selector to find the right path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code snippets so I'm not sure which selector you want to use but something as simple as the following should always select the first option in a select menu.

```
browser.elements('tag name', 'option', elements => {
    browser.elementIdClick(elements.value[0].ELEMENT);
});
```